# Is it standard to use HTTPS from client to Load Balancer, but not from LB to app server?

Tags: amazon-emr, amazon-elb

Just wondering if it is a standard practice to use AWS Load Balancer to handle the HTTPS and forward it to the application as HTTP so none of the app instances have to worry about ssl certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a common practice. One of the most important optimizations you could do for a website is to perform the SSL offloading geographically as close as possible to the client.

The [`SSL handshake`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257591) consists in a couple of exchanges between the client and the server in order to establish the SSL session. And by having the SSL offloading as close as possible to the user you are reducing the network latency. The load balancer could then dispatch the request to your webfarm which could be situated anywhere in the world.

Comment: Thanks Darin.  In practice, how much closer to the client can you get through EC2 than having a load balancer per region the client is in?

Comment: You mean like hosting your own load balancers compared to Amazon? That would be much more difficult rather than relying on established data centers and infrastructure.

Comment: Was just asking what you can really do beyond one lb per region.  I wouldn't consider doing anything outside of what amazon provides.

Comment: I just mentioned what is the best practice: do the SSL offloading as close geographically to the user as you possibly can.